# Postgres trigger does not find return

Tags: python, postgresql, triggers, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Here is my trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_played ()
  RETURNS trigger
AS
$BODY$
  DECLARE
    v_count_played integer;
BEGIN

    SELECT count(*) INTO STRICT v_count_played FROM history WHERE song_id = NEW.song_id;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'history count for song % not found', NEW.song_id;
      WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'history count did not aggregate';

    EXECUTE 'UPDATE song SET count_played = $1 WHERE id = $2'
        USING v_count_played, NEW.song_id;

    RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;


create trigger update_played_trigger
after insert on history
for each row
execute procedure update_played();
```

It gives the error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (psycopg2.InternalError) control reached end of trigger procedure without RETURN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misunderstood the `EXCEPTION` keyword. If I change your indenting to match how it works it might help you understand. `EXCEPTION` appears with `BEGIN` and `END` as part of a block like a `try {} catch {}` in other languages. So it works like this:

```
BEGIN

    SELECT count(*) INTO STRICT v_count_played 
    FROM history WHERE song_id = NEW.song_id;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'history count for song % not found', NEW.song_id;
    WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'history count did not aggregate';

        EXECUTE 'UPDATE song SET count_played = $1 WHERE id = $2'
            USING v_count_played, NEW.song_id;

        RETURN NULL;
END;
```

What happens here is that you run the `SELECT`. If there's a `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception you `RAISE`. If there's a `TOO_MANY_ROWS` exception you `RAISE`, then in the same block there is *unreachable code* after the `RAISE EXCEPTION` that does an `EXECUTE` and `RETURN`.

If there is no exception from the `SELECT` then no further action is taken, the procedure simply exits, returning nothing.

What I think you intended to write was:

```
BEGIN
    BEGIN
      SELECT count(*) INTO STRICT v_count_played FROM history WHERE song_id = NEW.song_id;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'history count for song % not found', NEW.song_id;
      WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'history count did not aggregate';
    END;

    EXECUTE 'UPDATE song SET count_played = $1 WHERE id = $2'
        USING v_count_played, NEW.song_id;

    RETURN NULL;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. I noticed it ran (now that is is fixed) for all the row in `history`, although it didn't on subsequent inserts. Is that how triggers work? If I add a new trigger it will on its first __run__ do it for every existing row even if only one new row is inserted?

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie Er. No. Triggers do nothing for existing rows and fire only for new rows. I suspect your trigger logic isn't right. If you don't figure it out please post a new question and link back to this one for context.